# ngIf with an evaluated variable as part of expression

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do the below:

```
ng-if="newItem.location == 'belowLesson{{lesson.Id}}'"
```

and it only works for ng-show.

In other words, if I set `newItem.location` equal to the string 'belowLesson28' and the lesson.Id in that scope is 28, I'd like this to work. I'd prefer not to use ng-show because it's a drag on the application (I use it a ton of times in an ng-repeat).

I'll put together a plunkr, just figured I'd put this out there sooner in case it's an obvious fix in syntax or something.

---

Here's a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UFpTQ6zsvlCWVep5Ai5I?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem in your plunkr is how you set the current item. Instead of

```
<button ng-click="chosenItem = {{item}}">
```

it should be

```
<button ng-click="chosenItem = item">
```

The second problem is that `ng-if` creates its own scope, and changing a value directly in the controller scope won't change the value previously stored (via inheritance) in the ng-id scope. You should thus store the chosen item in a sub-object, as shown in the following plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qOoZtnCqPuwvP3fGoUxw?p=preview

Comment: This answer plus your previous answer fixed me up for this problem, which is in a plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UFpTQ6zsvlCWVep5Ai5I?p=preview